# Is so called "Polymerized LiNb (Lithium Niobocene)" a possible compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers, chemistry-in-fiction

The so called "[Polymerized LiNb (Lithium Niobocene)](http://www.halopedia.org/Polymerized_lithium_niobocene)" is a fictional compound.

I heard about this substance being used for an interesting purpose. It reacts to mechanical stress or pressure by creating an electric charge (piezoelectricity) and, conversely, deforms, as if external pressure was applied, when voltage is applied. Apparently it was far more "piezoelectric" than any other similar compounds, i.e. it deformed far more drastically than other piezoelectric materials.

Does such a compound, or similar compounds, exist?

Comment: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/om980716r for real niobocene

Comment: So... Sorry if I've misunderstood, but I don't think anyone has answered my question. Can Polymerized Lithium Niobocene exist?

Comment: similar type of question as here http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35423/what-are-the-effects-of-lithium-dioxide-on-the-body

Comment: Be patient, your question is problematic - the naming is vague and improper as it's fictional material - you care more about polymerization, niobocene, lithium, or properties?

Comment: Accepted SCFlint's answer because I think my question was far too lacking in chemical knowledge. Sorry guys, my bad :/ - transfer Op's comment from question

Comment: I included the link and made clear that we are talking about a fictional substance. I think the paper @Mithoron linked is very interesting, but only from a structural point of view. It does not have the properties that are assigned to it in the fictional universe.

Comment: related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_muscle

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/140519/artificial-muscle-hasels-reaction

Comment: https://science.sciencemag.org/content/359/6371/61

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Materials such as Terfenol-D and Galfenol are magnetostrictive ferrous alloys that expand and contract in the presence of magnetic fields, as well as creating magnetic fields when acted on by a physical force.  Both these materials were developed at Ames Lab (formerly the Naval Ordnance Laboratory, that's why the material names end with -NOL).  Terfenol-D has the highest magnetostriction of any Fe-alloy, but the high rare earth content or Terbium and Dysprosium limits its commercial applications.

The "polymer" moniker for Lithium polymer batteries does no refer to the lithium metal or oxides, it only speak to the polymer electrolyte or a polymer casing.  It just a marketing term, no a chemical designation

So on to your question... Polymer, no.  Monomer, no.  Niobium has an extremely high melting point (nearly 2500C/4500F).  It is a very difficult material to melt.  Lithium boils around 1300C.  From a metallurgical processing point of view, you would need a chamber pressurized to several MPa with an inert gas to prevent the lithium from volatilizing as you attempt to alloy it with niobium.  You would also need some powerful magnetic stirring to attempt to keep the mix homogeneous since the lithium would literally float out of the solution.

Comment: Welcome on Chemistry SE! Unfortunately you answered pretty tricky question - OP's compound would be rather piezoelectric organometallic polymer than  magnetostrictive alloy as this LiNb (misleading) symbol suggests, but even then your answer is interesting.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake (I'm not well-versed in Chemistry at all), out of curiosity, what should I have written instead of LiNB?

Comment: @At0micCyb0rg you wrote as it were and you did OK - one has to work with data he has - it's authors of this info who made it misleading. Also maybe I'll try to answer, or someone else - you should be patient here ;)