# Artificial Muscle | HASEL's Reaction

Tags: physical-chemistry

I was watching a TED-talk on artificial muscle, [HASEL](https://youtu.be/Yi8tUJowAuo?t=516), where the inventor demos that an insulated oil in the presence of electric potential field gets displaced due to Maxwell stress inside oil.

Question: What are the chemical properties specifically of the oil that allows such contraction to occur? Can oil be replaced with other fluid of different chemical properties to amplify the contraction effect?

[image]

Comment: https://science.sciencemag.org/content/359/6371/61

Comment: @Mithoron +1 thanks for adding credible reference.

Comment: The oil is simply an inert, nonconducting, unpolar liquid. No chance to improve on that.

Comment: Btw. there is nothing "self-healing" in this contraption, and calling electrostatic attraction "Maxwell stress" is just an embarrassing try to make an nice little undergrad engineering project sound "scientific".

Comment: @Karl yes thats what I was wondering as well, how could it be self-healing. Looks exactly like what you described. Anyways you mentioned no chance to improve on that..but can actuation by means of contracting bags of oil be made significantly stronger like electromagnetic actuators? Induction/electromagnetism discharges too much heat. So this could be viable alternative if actuation is strong enough with reasonable form factor. Your thoughts on this?

Comment: The loss on this one here goes up as soon as you want to become faster, because of the viscosity of the oil, which produces heat. Also the loss goes up when you come close to the maximal deformation.

Comment: @Karl I makes so much sense now. And since oil is a poor conductor of heat, the performance might be suboptimal compared to metallic motors that dissipate heat faster. I didn't understand why the loss will go up when it come close to maximal deformation, shouldn't loss be linear?

Comment: A thinner (flatter) channel generally produces higher shear fields at the same volume flow rate, i.e. more friction. The linked paper unfortunately doesn't show the relevant graphs. That's Science magazine, mediocrity in paper form.

Comment: @Karl, best comment ever :) thanks for these useful comments.

Comment: @Karl What if a bigger channel is used? will the large volume produce lower shear fields? Arent there any ways to minimize friction and improve efficiency by clever design?